# python program behaves differently in python shell vs terminal

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I have a simple Python program that asks yes or no question and I validate that input.
If I run this Python shell, it runs fine. If I enter invalid characters it loops back to top of while.

However, if I run this in the terminal window and try to enter an invalid character it errors as shown below.

```
endProgram = 0
while endProgram != 1:
    userInput = input("Yes or No? ");
    userInput = userInput.lower();

    while userInput not in ['yes', 'no']:
        print("Try again.")
        break

    endProgram = userInput == 'no'
```

[image]

Comment: Are you using the same Python version on both? `input` changes behavior between 2 and 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can clearly see in the interactive shell you working in python 3.2.3 (background).  But I can not see the python version you're running from the command line (foreground).

On your raspberrypi, execute this command from the shell:

```
python --version
```

I am expecting to see python 2.x here, because the behaviour of `input()` differs between python 2 and python 3, in a way that would cause exactly the behaviour you have seen.

You might want to add a line like

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

To the top of your `.py` file, and then `chmod +x` on it.  Afterward you should be able to execute it directly (`./guipy01.py`) and the correct python interpreter will be selected automatically.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like your RPi is using Python 2; the `input` function does an `eval` there.
`input` in Python 3 is equivalent to `raw_input` in Python 2. (See [PEP-3111](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3111/))

Ideally, you should change your RPi interpreter to Python 3. Failing that, you can make it version-agnostic like so:

```
try:
    input = raw_input
except NameError:
    pass
```